# How do I pull changes from github repository to my local machine?

Tags: github

I've seen several questions/answers very similar to this but still not sure I understand if they are what I need.  So accept my apologies if this was covered before by something similar.

I have a private GitHub account with several repositories.  I created these from my mac, pushed them to GitHub and everything works great.

From my Ubuntu desktop, I did a git clone and pulled a couple of the repositories to that desk top.  Now from Ubuntu, I make a change to a file, add it, commit it, and push it to GitHub.

Question:
How (what command) on my mac do I use to pull that change down to my local repository so I get that change(s)?  UserName is JohnCowan, repo is sacnomadgolf.git

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You said you made the repo on your Mac. Then you can just do `git pull` in the folder you have the repository in.

A really good resource on Git, with explanatory illustrations about the "Git workflow":

http://git-scm.com/doc

Comment: Thank you, Sami, sir.  That was easy and painless.   I've been learning git and actually like it.  But, as they say, the more I learn the less I know.  Thanks again!